# How to disable text color in NSTextView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview, nscolorpanel

I have setup a NSColorPanel which I use to change the background color of a window. In the window there is also a NSTextView with some text in. The problem is that is that when I change the color of the background, the text color gets changed to into the same. I've tried finding ways to prevent this but with no success.

Comment: How did you tried to prevent it? Is your textview a firstResponder? According to `NSColorPanel` docs on [changeColor:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColorPanel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/changeColor:), it will be sent to firstResponder, so your textview might catch this event.

Comment: @Sega-Zero , Yes, the textview is first responder.

Comment: Well, then try to set another control as firstResponder temporarily, or subclass your text view with blank `changeColor:` method.

Comment: the second idea you said sounds good.

Comment: I *believe* if you set the color panel's target and action, it will send its action to the chosen target, rather than sending the default `-changeColor:` action to the first responder.

Answer (score 2):

Override the `NSTextView` `changeColor:` method and in that method, keep a outlet to the backgeoundView and instead of changing the textView's own color send it to the outlet:

```
IBOutlet NSView *changeColorTarget;
```

...

```
- (IBAction)changeColor:(id)sender {
    if(self.changeColorTarget) {    
        [NSApp sendAction:@selector(changeColor:) target:self.changeColorTarget forEvent:nil];
    } else {
        [super changeColor:sender];    
    }
}
```

--> that way the textview retains its original functionality except if you set the outlet